# Any way to accelerate transaction for a random cryptocurrency?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, block-propagation-time

I see all kinds of transaction confirmation times on [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/avg-confirmation-time), from really short to very long (to an unacceptable extent). I wonder if there's a way to control that in any way. Maybe by giving a bigger reward to the miners? Does the sender even have control over this? I know that Ethereum has some control over that, but is it possible for Bitcoin? What about other crypto coins/tokens?

Answer (score 1):

A bigger amount to the miners won't make them mine the block faster. It will only increase your chances to be in the next block AKA have your transaction confirmed faster.

In short the answer is no, the sender has no control when the next block will be mined, nor can they influence that with higher fees on their transaction.

"Miners" try to solve a mathematic problem using their collective computing power / hashrate.

A higher amount of fees doesn't drive the hashpower up, so it seems logic that the speed of "finding" a new hash / creating a new block doesn't increase.

Comment: Senders cannot control when the next block will be mined, but they certainly can influence how long it takes for their transaction to go in a block. If you pay a higher fee per byte than everyone else, you are very likely to be included in the next block, for example.

Comment: With `nor can they influence that with higher fees on their transaction.` I actually meant influencing the speed of when the next block is mined, Formulated that pretty bad.. :)